# Relative cell value within a INDIRECT formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have an INDIRECT formula below, the problem is the "F3" cell doesn't seem to be relative when I drag it to fill cells.

```
=INDIRECT("'Sheet 2'!F3")
```

How do I make the "F3" relative?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
=INDIRECT("'Sheet 2'!" & Cell("address", F3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
'for relative rows only
=indirect("'sheet 2'!f" & row(3:3))
'for relative rows and columns
=indirect("'sheet 2'!" & char(column(cx:cx)) & row(3:3))
'for relative columns only
=indirect("'sheet 2'!" & char(column(cx:cx)) & "3")
```